# Accessing and setting the instance variable of one class from another class

Tags: c#

I currently have a class called:

```
public class HeatmapComponent : GH_Component
```

I also have another class called:

```
public class HeatMap
```

Inside the `Heatmap` class I have two instance variables declared as:

```
public int _width;
public int _height;
```

I would like to be able to access and set the `_width` and `_height` variables from the `HeatmapComponent` class. I know this is a scope issue, but, I am a bit confused as to what needs to be done.

In my `HeatmapComponent` class, this was what I had in mind:

```
this._width = width; // width is declared somewhere in this class
this._height = height; // height is same as above
```

I apologize beforehand if this is a stupid question. Please let me know if I am missing code snippets. I'll be happy to provide.

Comment: Your question is unclear. And no you cannot access `private` members from outside the class.

Comment: as long as they are private they can only be accessible within the same class. if you make them public they will be accessible from other classes as well. Best practice is to wrap them in a property so you have some kind of control with who is doing what with your members: public int Width {get;set;}

Comment: I have tried setting it to public, but that did not solve the issue =/

Comment: BLUEPIXY could you clarify?

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to the discussion/question right here.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage it's not. I just wanted to vent it out.

Comment: Setting it to public won't help as you've set them as readonly.

Comment: I have set it to `public int _width` right now, but that still did not allow me to use `this._width = width;`

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @Snorre This is the error message: http://puu.sh/5PFId/f56daa2e7c.jpg

Comment: @thegreenCabbage your field is called `width`, not `_width`. That's why you get that error

Comment: you must declare _width. width and _width is two different members.

Comment: Sorry guys, I may have confused you all. `_width` is the instance variable in my other class, while `width` is locally declared (in this class right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to **set** the values of those two fields? They are `readonly`. You can do that **only** in the constructor.

```
public class HeatMap
{
    private readonly int _width;
    private readonly int _height;

    public HeatMap(int wid, int hei)
    {
        _width = wid;
        _height = hei;
    }
}
```

And, as it is with passing things through constructor's params, you can use/provide them **only** when building a new instance. That's why they are called `constructor` and `readonly fields`:

```
public class HeatmapComponent
{
    private int widthOfMap;
    private int heightOfMap;

    void createMapAndDoSomething() 
    {
        var hmap = new HeatMap(widthOfMap, heightOfMap);
        hmap.thing();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create a new HeatMap, and if you want to be able to set the width/height from some 'external' place at any point in time, then:

- they cannot be readonly
- some public way of changing them must exist

For example:

```
public class HeatMap
{
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public void SetSize(int wid, int hei)
    {
        _width = wid;
        _height = hei;
    }
}

public class HeatmapComponent
{
    private int widthOfMap;
    private int heightOfMap;

    private HeatMap oldMap;

    void changeTheSizes() 
    {
        oldMap.SetSize(widthOfMap, heightOfMap);
    }
}
```

Or sometimes even better, use properties:

```
public class HeatMap
{
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public int Width { set { _width = value; } }
    public int Height { set { _height = value; } }
}

public class HeatmapComponent
{
    private int widthOfMap;
    private int heightOfMap;

    private HeatMap oldMap;

    void changeTheSizes() 
    {
        oldMap.Width = widthOfMap;
        oldMap.Height = heightOfMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears I have these properties within the `Heatmap` class: http://puu.sh/5PFV0/3d87f79632.png

Comment: Should I also add a `set` within that?

Comment: After I have done so like this: http://puu.sh/5PGjg/66ccd1cd08.png, can you tell me how I can set this value in my other class?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

`readonly` keyword makes anything settable only in the `constructor`. Example:

```
class XYZ
{
    private readonly int x;
    public XYZ()
    {
        x = 10; //works
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        x = 100; //does not work since it is readonly
    }
}
```

Then there's the various access modifiers: `private` is only accessible in the class itself, `protected` is accessible in inherited classes and `public` is accessible anywhere. `Internal` is accessible within the same assembly.

```
public class HeatMapComponent
{
    HeatMap _map;
    public HeatMapComponent()
    {
        _map = new HeatMap();
    }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _map.Width = 10; //should work if Width is public and not readonly and if _map was initialized already, ie not null
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AD.Net, I have changed it to `public int _width;`, but that did not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question, you have one major, major issue: `readonly`. That means that the value of the variable *cannot be changed once the object is created. By anyone. Period*.

Now, you have a couple ways to do this. The first is to use properties like Snorre said. In effect, you'd get this:

```
public class HeatMap
{
   public int Width { get; set; }
   public int Height { get; set; }
}

public class HeatMapComponent
{
    private HeatMap myHeatMap; // Must have a reference to the object you want to change!

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        myHeatMap.Width = 10;
    }
}
```

Now, the obvious downside here is that ANYONE can change the properties of HeatMap. If for some reason you really, really want to make HeatMap's width and height editable **only** by the HeatMapComponent, you can make HeatMapComponent an [inner class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx), like this:

```
public class HeatMap
{
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public class HeatMapComponent
    {
        public HeatMap myHeatMap;

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            myHeatMap.width = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

however, I would strongly advise you to rethink what you're trying to do. Public inner classes are actually quite rare, in my experience, as they can violate OOP principles easily. A different application design may suit you better.

Comment: `That means that the value of the variable cannot be changed once the object is created. By anyone. Period.` - of course it can be. Just switch to ANY OTHER .Net language, other than C#, and it willbe visible as simple writable field. The CLR does not care about 'readonly'. It's purely C#'y thing. You can even change it through reflection, right in C#. This is how `readonly` differs from `const` !

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Well yes, if you go through reflection or IL editing/emission, everything is possible ^^, just like you could conceivably edit the value of a const at runtime by replacing the const value wherever it occurs. My point was that the C# compiler will not let the value be changed, which is what he cares about.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, and the problem is you are not understanding the lesson.

Here's a way to create your **HeatMap** class. It contains an overload so you can either set the Width and Height in the constructor or via a Set method:

```
public class HeatMap {

  public HeatMap() {
    Width = 0;
    Height = 0;
  }

  public HeatMap(int width, int height) {
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
  }

  public void Set(int width, int height) {
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
  }

  public int Width { get; private set; }

  public int Height { get; private set; }

}
```

To use this in your **HeatmapComponent** class, you only need to create an instance of your **HeatMap**. Here are two ways of doing that:

```
public HeatmapComponent() {
}

public void Test1(int width, int height) {
  var hm = new HeatMap(width, height);
  Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}", hm.Width, hm.Height);
}

public static void Test2(int width, int height) {
  var hm = new HeatMap();
  hm.Set(width, height);
  Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}", hm.Width, hm.Height);
}
```

Be sure  you understand what is going on, though.

Comment: This is not a homework question, I just want to clarify.

Comment: OK. Does this `{ get; private set; }` satisfy the **readonly** requirements? Sometimes, **readonly** means it needs to be a fixed value, and othertimes it means other classes should not be able to modify it.